# how to add google maven repository to remote repository in artifactory

Tags: artifactory

I try add https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2 and https://maven.google.com but no luck. How add repository?

Comment: What kind of errors did you get? You should be able to configure the URLs you mentioned as a remote repository in Artifactory and include the remote repository in your maven configuration.

Comment: no errors. nothong happen